# How to convert counterup2 to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How to convert this counterUp2 jquery to vanilla javascript ?

```
var counterUp = window.counterUp["default"]; // import counterUp from "counterup2"
  var $counters = $(".counter");
  /* Start counting, do this on DOM ready or with Waypoints. */
  $counters.each(function (ignore, counter) {
    var waypoint = new Waypoint( {
      element: $(this),
      handler: function() { 
        counterUp(counter, {
          duration: 1000,
          delay: 16
        }); 
        this.destroy();
      },
      offset: 'bottom-in-view',
    } );
  });
```

Thanks

Comment: use this code, but only work in one first class `const myCounters = function () {

    var count_active = function count_active() {
      var counterUp = window.counterUp["default"]; // import counterUp from "counterup2"
      var el = document.querySelector('.counter');

      counterUp( el, {
          duration: 1000,
          delay: 16,
      });
    }

    // if window active
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
      count_active();
    });
  };
  myCounters();`

Comment: If you could say what's the input and what's the (counterup(2)'s) expected output, I could try to help.

Comment: hello iAmOren, I want to use CounterUp2 js in pure javascript. in jquery version like this https://codepen.io/mnunes/pen/RXQqXz

Comment: Pure JavaScript rules!  Unfortunately, the link didn't clarify anything for me.  If you can tell me what it does: what you send, what you get/expect to get back...  I'm not in favor of jquery either...

Comment: this https://codepen.io/mnunes/pen/RXQqXz  is using jquery, and I need pure javascript not using jquery library

Comment: ?  I guess I cannot help you...  If you said something like: I need a function that returns a square of a number, and here is what I tried, or: I've got an array of objects [{id:1,qty:3},{id:2,qty:5}] and I need to sum the qtys, or: how to make clicking of a button to run a function, or: this is what I send "....." and this is what I get "..." - how to achieve that in pure javascript?  = you didn't give me information to work with, twice, I can't understand from code(pen.io) that I cannot even run, what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution :)

```
<script src="/assets/js/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/counterUp.min.js"></script>
<script>
  (() => {
    const counterUp = window.counterUp['default'];
    const counters = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.counterUp'));
    for (const counter of counters) {
      new Waypoint({
        element: counter,
        handler() { 
          counterUp(counter); 
          this.destroy();
        },
        offset: 'bottom-in-view'
      });
    }
  })();
</script>
```